# How to change the color of selected text/code in PHPStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, color-scheme, code-editor

Im switching code editors and trying to rebuild my color scheme from the previous one, from Sublime Text to PHP Storm.

What i can't find is: 
How to change the color of selected text/code - to be more specific the background of the selected text and the color of the font of the selected text?

And is there a way in PHPStorm to make the color for ID's and Classes different (for HTML)?

Comment: File -> Settings -> Colors & Fonts. Most of the settings you are after will be in this area for the Editor, as for the separate colours for IDs/Classes I imagine it is possible by potentially changing the language defaults, by default I *think* they are both set as attributes so get coloured the same. I imagine that could be altered although I have never personally tried to, nice idea though!

Comment: I will try to change language defaults. But for the other settings i know the are there but, i can find those specific settings, right now the selection is to dark and it can be distinguished from the background of the editor.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[select_background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJdNx.jpg)

please go to file -> settings -> IDE settings ->colors & fonts -> general -> save default scheme and then make changes in selection background choose any color in your background  please check the image

Comment: thanks for taking time to help, but i have tried that too, i will be more specific now: when you open a document with code in it php/html/js doesn't matter, and use the mouse to drag and select a block of code, there is a background in different color to that selection, what i try to do is to find the settings to change that color.

Comment: please go to file -> settings -> IDE settings ->colors & fonts -> general -> save default scheme and then make changes in selection background choose any color in your background  please check the image

Comment: That's it! thanks a lot, i don't know how i've missed that thanks

Answer (score 9):

On Windows, assuming you're in a custom/child theme, follow this path:

**File** > **Settings** > **Editor** > **Color Scheme** > **General** > **Editor** > **Selection background**

[How to change the highlight color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLiht.jpg)

Comment: Worked on 2018.2-Linux

Answer (score -1):

You can use directly a template for color scheme (THEME PHPStorm).
Download and install this and you will have a Sublime text 2 color in PHPStorm : [PHPStorm color Scheme theme like Sublime Text 2](http://www.phpstorm-themes.com/theme/monokai-sublime)

Comment: i know that, the problem is that i've used modified version of the theme [Glacier](http://smashinghub.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Best-sublime-text-2-and-3-theme-for-2014-3.png)  for ST3 and that specific theme is not available for PHPStrom, i've searched for it